# How to use FS from NodeJs ? "I'm `FS` modules"

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

Before asking I read alot in this same forum about this problem and couldn't find a solution.

This is my js file:

```
const fs = require( 'fs' );

fs.readFile( './test.html', (err, data) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(data);
})
```

And this is the result:
["I'm `fs` modules"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7ypd.png)

I read that this is because this is not the native "fs" package from NodeJs and that I might have a "troll" one.

Alright, I did

```
npm uninstall fs
npm uninstall -g fs
```

Still the problem remains.
So I uninstalled NodeJs completely from my machine, restart, installed again, restart again and still the same issue.

I have no problem with the "http" package for example.

My version of **npm** - **6.14.11**, **node** - **14.15.4**, **webpack** - **4.46.0**

I'm stuck on this on I have the feeling that I am being trolled or just missing something absolutely obvious.

Can you please help me resolve this ?

Comment: Probably You are using `fs` inside a browser code.
Browsers can't access file system, only the server can. But both can access stuff like `http`.

Comment: Are you bundling your code with webpack?  Are you then trying to run your code in the browser?  If so, there is no `fs` module when running in the browser.

Comment: Ok so the "fs" module cannot be use in the js file my index.html will load ?

Comment: Yes.
Despite both sides - client and server - uses the same language - JavaScript - they have slightly different sets of libraries.
The client (browser) has DOM stuff and the server has file system. And you can't use these "exclusive" stuff on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the webpack error it seems that You are trying to use `fs` inside a browser.
Browser JavaScript can't access file system so `fs` package will not load.
Instead of using file api try to send an http request to the server and respond with corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

1. npm init
2. mkdir
3. install axios
4. touch index.js
5. copy past betow code
6. run node index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios').default;
axios.get('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I7ec--mRp-e93mM7Hm50PAQXtFP-cviR/view?usp=sharing').then((res) => {
    fs.writeFile('abc.txt', res.data, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log("File created successfully");
            fs.open('abc.txt', 'r+', (err, fd) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('file opened');
                    fs.readFile('abc.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Read");
                            fs.close(fd, (err, data) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Closed");
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
})

//Output

/* 
File created successfully
file opened
Read
Closed
*/
```

1. List item